# When tying to access YAML file NullPointPointer is thrown

Tags: java, intellij-idea, inputstream, embedded-resource

With this code I'm trying to access a yaml file that's located in my resources folder in an intellij project, to receive some properties:

```
 InputStream inputStream = this.getClass()
                .getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream("configuration.yaml");
```

But for some reason it appears to not find it and also `requireNonNull(inputStream);` seems to throw a NullPointer. The projects works for a colleague, but I can't get it to work on my machine. Weird thing is the same project only without a few minor changes already worked on my machine and I have no idea what changed to break it like that.

Any help is appreciated greatly.

Comment: How are you compiling? Build systems like maven can handle resource locations differently. Take a look at the actual, compiled jarfile you can make with this, and see if those resources are present in one build but not the other

Comment: Verify that the resource folder is part of the class path or build path and check the name, e.g. for letter case and hidden characters. In modular environments, `.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/configuration.yaml")` is preferable, to provide more context, though you should use `Actual.class` instead of `getClass()`, so you can’t end up at a different context of a subclass. Without further information, it’s hard to give more suggestions.

Comment: I use gradle, but I'm pretty much new to it. How should I take a look at the jarfile?

Comment: How can I verify if the resources folder is part of the class path?

Answer (score 0):

check whether the file is really located in you resource folder.
you can try this classloader:

```
ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("configuration.yaml");
```

Comment: I have it in resources and I get the same error with this class loader